# Equal space between Bootstrap column elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**CSHTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 box">
        <h2>Test1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create &raquo" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Test1", new { area = ""})'" /></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 box">
        <h2>Test2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create &raquo" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Test2", new { area = ""})'" /></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 box">
        <h2>Test3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create &raquo" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Test3", new { area = ""})'" /></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QFtKwSs4dK)

How do I create equal space between these 3 `div`'s and keep it centered?  This goes underneath my `carousel`.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by equal spacing? As in, you want to add whitespace on either side of your columns? Does this include on the outer edges, or just in between columns?

Comment: @Serlite just in between columns.  but i am realizing that this might not be possible due to the fact that the 3 bootstrap columns equal up to 12 (`col-lg-4`) and bootstrap only allows up to 12 columns per row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a flex box on the parent `.row`.

```css
.box{
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex:1;
}
.box:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Test1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create",="" "test1",="" new="" {="" area="" })'"=""></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Test2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create",="" "test2",="" new="" {="" area="" })'"=""></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
  <div class="box">
    <h2>Test3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p><input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create",="" "test3",="" new="" {="" area="" })'"=""></p>
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Great! I cleaned up the snippet code a little bit too.

Answer (score 1):

Using only the Bootstrap scaffolding classes, this isn't too tricky to do - you just have to started using nested columns, and applying offset classes to successive columns. For example:

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 box">
        <h2>Test1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create ",=" " "test1 ",=" " new=" " {=" " area=" " })'"="">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 box">
        <h2>Test2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create ",=" " "test1 ",=" " new=" " {=" " area=" " })'"="">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 box">
        <h2>Test3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Create »" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" create ",=" " "test1 ",=" " new=" " {=" " area=" " })'"="">
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

*(Note that you'll have to expand the snippet to full screen to see it working, since otherwise it'll use the mobile media query.)*

Comment: Glad I could help out, regardless of which solution you end up going with!